# Average of 2d list by only adding single row and finding the average of that single row

Tags: python, list

I want to find the average of a 2-dimensional list in Python.

This is an example of my list:

```
list = [[x, y, 1], [x, y, 1], [x, y, 2]]
```

I want to add the third row and find the average of that row only.

This is my code:

```
def averageList(list):
    averagefile = []
    sum = 0
    for count in range(0, len(list)):
        try:
            sum = sum + float(list[count][2])
        except ValueError:
            print ''
    average = sum / len(list[count])
    averagefile.append(average)
    print averagefile

    #return averageList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['x','y',1], ['x','y',1], ['x','y',2]]
>>> sum(entry[-1] for entry in L) / float(len(L))
1.3333333333333333
```

This is same as:

```
>>> sum(entry[2] for entry in L) / float(len(L))
```

since the last position is index `2`.

Comment: make that entry[2] instead of entry[-1] just to mimic the original code.

Comment: I did not know you could use negative list indices like that in Python.  Very cool!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate using map:

```
>>> li=[['x','y',1], ['x','y',1], ['x','y',2]]
>>> sum(map(lambda sl: sl[2],li))/float(len(li))
1.3333333333333333
```

You can also use zip:

```
>>> sum(zip(*li)[2])/float(len(li)
1.3333333333333333
```